# Certification in PHP and SEO

Tags: php, wordpress, seo, magento-1.6, symfony-2.3

Can anyone please guide me which kind of certifications are available for php and seo? I am a php developer as well as a Lecturer. And i want to teach and guide my students. I know symfony and wordpress. But other then this what kind of certification is in demand in current/future market. I am ready to learn new technology even.

Comment: This really isn't the proper forum for this sort of thing. Although, the only decent PHP cert I know of is ZCPE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No certifications are or should be needed.  As for new tech, `node.js` is very used right now in the market. If you're a `javascript` developer and want to learn `node.js`, you will have a very easy time. Note that `node.js` is commonly used with `nosql` databases, such as `mongodb`, `couchdb` and quite a few more.

If you haven't tried those technologies, it might be a good time to start learning/using/mastering them. Also, I recommend you start using `git` if you haven't. You can do wonders with `git`.

If you work as a front-end developer once in a while, I extremely urge you to get right on `Grunt.js`, since Grunt is extremely useful for a numerous tasks in front end, and it can at some extent, be used for backend, including some php tasks.

NodeJS website: http://nodejs.org/

mongodb website: http://www.mongodb.org/

couchdb website: http://couchdb.apache.org/

git website: http://git-scm.com/

grunt website: http://gruntjs.com/

I think that's enough for you to get busy for a while. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot Yisera... I am pleased to have such informative answer from you... :)

Comment: If you think my post is what you are looking for, please mark it as an answer. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 2):

Personally I don't think any certification is needed, especially in the programming industry (even for lecturesr). It's more important to show that you have been involved with important projects. Working experience with bigger companies or open-source projects will prove your expertise.

With that being said, there is one from W3C:
http://www.w3schools.com/cert/cert_php.asp

Another one is mentioned by Zarazthuzatra, ZCE:

http://www.zend.com/en/services/certification/

Comment: Thanks for the guidance Dweller, Actually i don't want certification for me only. I think if my students (who are doing live project work) can get certification exam clear then MNC companies can distinguish them easily from others and it may become easy for them to recruit right candidate from campus. Is it worth-full? What you think? ... :)

Comment: @KaushalBhatt Then I recommend ZCE. It is designed for enterprise level PHP applications that are built upon Zend Framework (one of few PHP frameworks developed for corporations). Honestly, I don't think multi-national companies will ever use PHP. PHP has a strong library but the language itself is quite weak. The trend right now is Ruby for small-mid websites, Java/Scala for big websites (like Amazon, Twitter, Ebay).